# Name for ring that contains $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit. Is there a standard way of saying that $\mathbb{Q} \subset R$?

One possibility is to say that $R$ is uniquely divisible (as an abelian group), because  that the canonical map $R \to R \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}$ is an isomorphism equivalent to $\mathbb{Q} \subset R$,  but maybe there is a more standard name.

Comment: @egreg Comments are supposed to be used to clarify, not answer the question. See [How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) for more information.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I was expecting closure. I’ve seen much less trivial questions closed in a show time.

Comment: @egreg What's the connection between anticipating closure and using the comments in a contraindicated way?  Do existing answers make questions harder to close?  If the reason is because we're not supposed to give answers to questions needing closure, then I'm pretty sure answers in the comments are no better than real answers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$R$ is uniquely divisible iff $R$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra. But that does not mean that $R$ contains $\mathbb{Q}$: The zero algebra $0$ is the exception.

So if you really want a name for commutative rings with $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq R$, these are the non-trivial commutative $\mathbb{Q}$-algebras.